# Site login failed due to strange warning

Tags: login

I have been using your website designer for some time now and am enjoying it. Recently however, I can't access my own site to edit and update. My site is called Actionnfl.com and I access it by searching "Actionnfl.com/wp-admin." Usually this works, but now when I do this, a white page appears that says, "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/applie40/public_html/actionnfl.com/wp-content/themes/boldgrid-florentine/functions.php:9) in /home/applie40/public_html/actionnfl.com/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1179." A few days ago I added a line of code in my functions.php and this is most likely the reason why this appears. Help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May be your problem at functions.php of boldgrid-florentine theme.
Open this file in cpanel and find out the problematic syntax. For details https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting#How_do_I_solve_the_Headers_already_sent_warning_problem.3F